# How to set custom radio group into redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

What should I do to set ColoredRadioGroup into state of my form? Tried few things from redux-form docs but it didn't help. I heard about passing onChange and value props but I'm not sure how to do it in my case.

**ColoredRadioGroup.js:**

```
class CustomRadioGroup extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: props.defaultValue,
    };
  }

  setValue = (value) => {
    this.setState(() => ({ value }));
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    if (this.props.onChange) {
      this.props.onChange(this.props.data.filter(elem => elem.value === event.target.value)[0]);
    }
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <RadioGroup
        style={this.props.groupStyle}
        name={this.props.groupName}
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      >
        <FormControlLabel
          value="green"
          control={
            <GreenRadio
              icon={<CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon />}
              checkedIcon={<CheckBoxIcon />}
            />
          }
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          value="yellow"
          control={
            <YellowRadio
              icon={<CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon />}
              checkedIcon={<CheckBoxIcon />}
            />
          }
        />
    ...
      </RadioGroup>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomRadioGroup;
```

**In form file:**

```
  <Field
    component={props => <ColoredRadioGroup value={props.input.value} />}
    name="agent_group"
    type="radio"
  />
```

Answer (score 1):

When you wrap your component in `Field`
redux-form will pass input and meta objects through props.
in your way you are only passing `props.input.value` prop.
you need to use `props.input.onChange` in your `handleChange` to update that specific field in redux store.
refactor it like so:

```
 <Field
  component={ColoredRadioGroup}
  name="agent_group"
/>
```

and you should see the props in your custom component.

Look at https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/api/field.md/#props for more info.